# AJAX POST from Dropdown selection in codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, codeigniter

I'm working on a project that is needed to post from Ajax when the client make a selection, my code was working in the beginning but I'm not sure if did something wrong in the process and it stopped working. It is done in codeigniter 3, this is my code:

**HTML:**

```
<td>
<select class="proposals_items_status" name="proposals_items_status">
    <option value="">Seleccione</option>
    <option value="Aceptado" <?php if($v_item->status=='Aceptado') {?> selected="selected"<?php }?>>Aceptar</option>
    <option value="Rechazado" <?php if($v_item->status=='Rechazado') {?> selected="selected"<?php }?>>Rechazar</option>
</select>
<span class="loader" style="display:none">
    <img style="width:32px;" src="https://comm.medias.polytechnique.fr/static/mediaserver/images/live.gif" />
</span>
```

**Script:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('.proposals_items_status').change(function() {
        var  proposals_items_status =    $(this).val();
        $('.loader').show();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '<?= base_url() ?>client/proposals/update_status/',
            data: { 
                   'proposals_items_status': proposals_items_status, 
                   'id': <?= $v_item->proposals_items_id ?>,
            },
            success: function(msg){ 
                 $('.loader').hide();
            }
        });
    });
});

</script>
```

**Controller:**

```
public function update_status()
{
    $proposals_items_status =   $_REQUEST['proposals_items_status'];

    $id                     =   $_REQUEST['id'];

    $this->proposal_model->update_status($id, $proposals_items_status);

   exit;

}
```

**Model:**

```
function update_status($id,$status)
{
    $data = array('status'=> $status);  
    $this->db->where('proposals_items_id', $id);    
    $this->db->update('tbl_proposals_items', $data);        
}
```

**UPDATE:**

I noted that the post goes duplicated when only one selection

[image]

Comment: did you recently set $config['csrf_protection'] = TRUE;?
If yes then kindly add csrf_name and csrf_value in AJAX.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response, if i add the csrt protection to true i can't even login in my dashboard